# Use PERFORM ... with dynamic query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I want just lock row, but I also need do this with dynamic query, so I do:

```
...
EXECUTE 'PERFORM 1 FROM table_name WHERE id = $1 FOR UPDATE' USING variable;
...
```

Gives error: `syntax error at or near "PERFORM"`

So, there is no possible to use `PERFORM` in dynamic query ?

Comment: Change `PERFORM` to `SELECT`. You don't need PERFORM in a dynamic query.

Comment: @eurotrash - Yes, just I prefer to no create additional variable and use `SELECT ... INTO`. If possible, I prefer to use `PERFORM`.

Comment: You don't need to SELECT INTO anything, just use SELECT. It's not the same as doing SELECT in straight plpgsql, in that case you would need a destination for your query results, in dynamic EXECUTE you don't.

Comment: @eurotrash - Nice, thanks, I didn't knew that.